# Re-use inherited FK-Relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am creating an application using C#/.net 4.5 and EF 6 and was wondering if I could do the following somehow:

I have two base classes like:

```
public class BaseItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<BaseRevision> Revisions { get; set; }
}

public class BaseRevision
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public BaseItem Item { get; set; }
}
```

Now I derive both of them like the following:

```
[Table("ContentItems")]
public class ContentItem : BaseItem
{
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}

[Table("ContentRevisions")]
public class ContentRevision : BaseRevision
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine and EF even handles queries like:

```
var revisions = db.ContentItems.Where(i => i.Revisions.Any(r => (r as ContentRevision).Text.Contians("ABC")));
```

This is converted to SQL as I would expect, but I would like to "get rid if the `as`" (it causes much more complication in some other cases).

I tried using generics for `BaseItem`, but that is not supported by EF so I tried the following:

```
[Table("ContentItems")]
public class ContentItem : BaseItem
{
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    public List<ContentRevision> ContentRevisions { get; set; }
}

[Table("ContentRevisions")]
public class ContentRevision : BaseRevision
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public ContentItem ContentItem { get; set; }
}
```

So I could use the above query like:

```
var revisions = db.ContentItems.Where(i => i.ContentRevisions.Any(r => r.Text.Contians("ABC")));
```

But I can't get it working using the inherited foreign key "Item_Id" in the "BaseItems" table. EF allways wants to create a second FK-Relation using a new "ContentItem_Id" key in the "ContentItems" table, which would duplicate the relation (and maybe cause some other side-effects).

**Is this somehow possible (or has someone a better idea to solve/improve this problem/pattern)?**

UPDATE: Demo project can be downloaded [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n6z18lrk4dt68jr/EfGenericTest.zip). If you add a new migration it will create the second FK-mapping I do not want...

Comment: Are there tables for BaseItem and BaseRevision in the database (4 tables) or just ContentItem and ContentRevision (2 tables) that are actually generated?

Comment: Sorry if that is an obvious question, I just wanted to make sure I understand correctly. It is a good question.

Comment: @acarlon: There are 4 tables generated, because of the `Table` attribute and I want it that way as I have MANY classes derived from that base...

Comment: I have created a chat room here with a question to keep the comments from becoming cluttered: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37171/re-use-inherited-fk-relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT :**

You don't need to add a complicated relation here, that's exactly what the OfType<> is intended for.

When you want to access your ContentItems only, insteed of creating a new list in your inheriteded object you use the BaseItem list and write :

```
(i is a BaseItem)
i.Revison.OfType<ContentItem>
```

You'll use this common list for storing all of your differents BaseItems.
Thanks to the compiler, it's developper error free because when using the OfType<> func, you'll only get the typed objects you want.

**Initial Answer :**
If your initial problem is that all of you revisions are not ContentRevision and that it cause your query to fail on the `as` conversion, you should write it this way :

```
var revisions = db.ContentItems.Where(i => i.Revisions.OfType<ContentRevision>.Any(r => r.Text.Contains("ABC")));
```

Comment: No, the `as` works fine, I just don't wan't to us it as it is not really "save" as you could also cast to the wrong type...

Comment: You want to have a List<BaseItem> Revisions in your BaseItem, and a List<ContentItem> in your ContentItem. You don't need to add a complicated relation here, that's exactly what the OfType<> is intended for. Insteed of writing i.ContentRevision for accessing your CotentItems, you write i.Revison.OfType<ContentItem>. You have only 1 list insteed of two, you don't need to sync them, you could put a lot of different BaseItems in the same list and only access the ones you want easly. They're all saved in db, and it's developper error free. Because compiler won't let you try to use  the wrong type.

Comment: Try before you buy, you won't regret ;)

Comment: Thanks for that explanation - I thought the `OfType` is just another form of casting. Please edit the explanation to your answer and I will accpet yours, as it is the best solution so far...

Comment: Done. As i'm a little lazy, I re-used a lot of my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the ForeignKey data annotations to tell entity framework which properties to use for the foreign key. I.e.

```
public class BaseItem
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public List<BaseRevision> Revisions { get; set; }
}

public class BaseRevision
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("Id")]
  public BaseItem Item { get; set; }
}

[Table("ContentItems")]
public class ContentItem : BaseItem
{
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}

[Table("ContentRevisions")]
public class ContentRevision : BaseRevision
{
  public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

or using the Fluent API to specify the relationship i.e. for the BaseItem class

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseItem>()
.HasMany(t => t.Revisions)
.WithRequired(t => t.Item)
.HasForeignKey(t => t.Id);
```

Comment: I tried it using the data annotation, but not with the fluent API. Will try that and report back...

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class BaseItem
 {
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public List<BaseRevision> Revisions { get; set; }
  }

 public class BaseRevision
 {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Int BaseItemID{get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("BaseItemID")]
     public BaseItem Item { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Better, as it does not create a separate mapping column, but still creates a new FK (and an invalid index)...